# Metal detector coil SHIELDING?

Tags: analog, grounding, magnetics, interference, magnetic-flux

Many designs of coils, of metal detectors, are shielded (Faraday shield).

- Should this be used in a gravity-fed detector (like the sketched one)?
- What's the shield for?

NOTE:

The coils are arranged inside a metalic cabinet, which is grounded.

[image: Gravity feed]

Comment: The shielding may be used to improve sensitivity and also to protect external equipment from the magnetic fields of the driven search coils.  Shielding is good to prevent false detection from outside the sample zone.

Comment: @KalleMP When you talk about shielding, do you mean something like this ([link]http://60minutemetal.com/27812/metal-detector-search-coil/metal-detector-search-coil-20-with-metal-detector-search-coil/)? Applied to Tx and Rxs coils? Or the metal cabinet does enough work?

Comment: That is the normal electrostatic shielding.  You can see it is a conductive shield that is broken at a point to avoid a shorted turn which would attenuate all the induced magnetic signals.  The metalic cabinet in your picture is there for magnetic and outside electrostatic shielding.  The pipe walls should be made to provide internal electrostatic shielding, you want the magnetic fields to penetrate the product.  A non magnetic conductive tube with a slit or graphite like the other answer talks about are needed there.  The whole box is then the electrostatic shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphite type shields that line the apertures of industrial metal detectors are only required when the material being passed (in which you are searching for metal contaminants) is partially electrically conductive and causes what is known as "product effect". If the material is not conductive (but has a significant electric permittivity) then the graphite sheet is also required.

Industrial metal detectors in the food and pharmaceutical industry do make use of extensive product-effect algorithms to ignore the "signal" produced by "clean" product but the graphite sheets are still needed to homogenize the electric fields in the aperture. The effect that a poorly distributed electric field in the aperture has is difficult to eradicate with just algorithms.

The electric fields arise because the central coil generating flux is driven from a voltage source and that voltage source creates the electric fields in the aperture. These need to be "smoothed-out" in order to prevent effects that an algorithm cannot adequately deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The shields should be installed in all metal detectors. Thay are there because coils are basically antennas, which means that a lot of interference and, therefore, messed up results. The shield is especially important in single-coil detectors (using a colpitz oscillator, for example), but is also neccesary in double-coil ones.

Answer (score 0):

For the metal detectors used in the discovery of buried objects the shields is needed to neutralise the capacitance offered by the ground.

The protection offered against disturbances is irrelevant because those interference are outside of the frequency range of the instruments, for example 10 kHz to 100 kHz .

The book from Carl Moreland and George Overtone "Inside the Metal Detector" is very useful to everyone who wants know more about detecting metals.